# Alert View issues after popping view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a stack that looks like this:
Navigation Controller -> Table View Controller -> Another Table View Controller.

Whats happening is that in a method in `AnotherTableViewController` I show an alert view, and then pop the controller off the stack. The alert view displays fine, except that after clicking the dismiss button, it throws an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` which I know is what happens when you send a message to a released object. What I think is happening is that the alert view is sending the `dismissWithClickedButtonAtIndex:Animated:` message to the delegate which I had assigned to `AnotherTableViewController` but it got released after I popped it so now after the message is sent, it throws the error. 
How should I go about showing an alert view after popping the controller (or right before)?

I also am using properties in `AnotherTableViewController` and displaying them in my alert view.

Comment: Can you put relevant code of `dismissWithClickedButtonAtIndex:Animated ` ?

Comment: I don't have anything for it, the alert view sends it automatically, I just haven't overrided it.

Answer (score 3):

While showing `UIAlertView` you should not set the delegate like below,

```
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Please enter current and new password" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
```

as you are not doing anything on the delegate methods this solution should work

Comment: Thanks, I don't know why I didn't think of this before. I'll accept your answer as soon as possible.